# How to set enum to null if value of enum is null?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, enums

I'm passing parameter enum type nullable to my controller.

and Need to set this parameter to null without using if else condition.

I'm trying like this..

```
Category? categoryID = CategoryID.HasValue ? CategoryID : null ? CategoryID : CategoryID;
```

how can i accomplish this? help me.

Comment: what is the type of `CategoryID`?

Comment: Your nested tertiary if statements won't compile. What is the flow you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I resolved it. actually two conditional operation was not required. one was enough
Category? categoryID = CategoryID.HasValue ? CategoryID : null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got Solution for this.

```
Category? categoryID = CategoryID.HasValue ? CategoryID : null
```

Produced the desired result for me.